# Ease of data retrieving between NodeJs and PHP

Tags: php, mysql, node.js

I'm currently developing a real time project where a client (local) will attempt to connect to the server (cloud). I had successfully done it using socketio. But the problem that I'm encounter is that it not that flexible to retrieving data from php (I want to use php for db retrieval as nodejs is not user friendly for much complex query) to nodejs.

Any better method for ease of data retrieval between Nodejs and PHP?

Answer (score 0):

You should get the data from DB directly in Node.js.

For that you can use **[Sequelize.js](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/)** an ORM for **Node** (MySQL, Postgres, SQLite and MSSQL) that will help you to create simple and performant queries.